# How to resolve reference or assembly dependency

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I tried calling this reference with the following, but it's not compiling:

```
this.crystalReportViewer1 = 
    new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
```

> "could not resolve reference. could not locate assembly"
>   Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Is your project .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: is a .NET Framework

Comment: The message is REALLY tells you what is wrong with your project. Now, can you read it?

Comment: After you check that you have added a reference to CrystalDecisions, check the Object Browser for the class you want. The hierarchy in you new statement looks odd.